# Ordering of Polynomial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Take a point $x \in [0,1]$.
Now take a polynomial, $p$ of degree $n$

If I know that $\max(p'(x), p''(x),\dots, p^{(n-1)}(x)) = p'(x)$, what can I say about $p(x)$?

So far I haven't spent too much time on this other than to ascertain that there should be polynomials where this condition is satisfied for all $x \in [0,1]$. Just let the $(n-1)^{th}$ coefficient

An example of one that always exists is $p(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 6x + 1$ where the first derivative is always greater than the second. For this I find that for $x \in [0,1]$ the first derivative is also larger than $p(x)$.

The regions(in terms of $x$) this is true on must be closed intervals along with a finite number of individual points. Therefore if they are dense in some interval they must cover the whole interval.